# Cocos2d-x - How can I add a sprite in the GameScene which is called from another class?

Tags: sprite, cocos2d-x

I have a GameScene class which is similar to HelloWorldScene in the project template. How can I add a sprite and display in the scene of the GameScene with addChild method which is in the another class?

Example, I have 2 class: GameScene and Board is a normal class. In init method of GameScene I call board->initBoard() with board is a object of Board class. How I add addChild(sprite) in initBoard() ?

I tried with some ways but it still is not sucessfull. I'm using Cocos2d-x v3.0rc1.

Comment: For better response please go with http://gaming.stackexchange.com/

Comment: first you need create sprite and add in init method of GameScene then replace HelloWorldScene with GameScene. Check out SceneTest example in TestCpp

Comment: @Cocos2dx : Example, I have 2 class: GameScene and Board is a normal class. In init method of GameScene I call board->initBoard() with board is a object of Board class. How I add addChild(sprite) in initBoard() ?

Comment: You can send pointer of GameScene in Board class member like `initBoard(GameScene* pScene)` and add child to `pScene` object.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is a bad design! Why is a child class adding stuff to its parent while being initialized itself?
But if it is such a requirement, then I would do something like,

> > > the bad way

(In GameScene) 
    Board* board = new Board();
    this->addChild(board);
    board->initBoard();

```
meanwhile in boardclass,
void Board::initBoard(){
.
.
.
 getParent()->addChild(sprite);
}
```

Even though I don't like it, it will work. 
Yet another way would be,

> > > the OK way...

```
Board::initBoardWithParent(GameScene* scene){
.
.
.
 scene->addChild(sprite);
}
```

in GameScene...

```
Board* board = new Board();
board->initBoardWithParent(this);
```

In this case(for some people), errors start popping up... so make sure ur scene is declared with a preprocessor...otherwise it will make ur compiler scream as it would get crazy compiling GameScene since it is using Board which itself is using GameScene...

```
#ifndef __GAME_SCENE_H__
#define __GAME_SCENE_H__

 ...
 ...

class GameScene :  ....
#endif // __GAME_SCENE_H__
```

> > > The decent way...

Yet anotherway would be that you override the ADDCHILD Method of ur Board class...
And as you do that, make sure you pass an extra parameter indicating that this is a special ADDCHILD, and once u get there... using either of the 2 methods mentioned earlier to add the sprite to the GameScene object.

Hope this helps!